# How to get number of cores used in current job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

`SparkContext` has `getExecutorMemoryStatus` method. But it's for memory status of an Executor.

Is there any way how to get `core` status? I use Spark Standalone Cluster.

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately. Such a feature would be great!

Comment: i know its bit old question, but tried to put all options for the other users. please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Out of below probably option 3 is the one you are looking for..

- ***Option 1*** : Spark web ui gives me the information about total cores and used cores.

[image]

- ***Option 2*** : Defaults :

  `sc.defaultParallelism` typically set to the number of worker cores in your cluster
- ***Option 3*** : Can use [ExectorInfo.totalCores](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/ExecutorInfo.html) like below and try... it should work.

docs says

> `public class ExecutorInfo extends Object`
> Stores information about an
> ***executor to pass from the scheduler to SparkListeners.***

```
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.{SparkListener, SparkListenerExecutorAdded}

/**
  * Logs info of added executors.
  */
final class ExecutorLogger extends SparkListener {

  override def onExecutorAdded(executorAdded: SparkListenerExecutorAdded): Unit =
    println(s"\rExecutor ${executorAdded.executorId} added: ${executorAdded.executorInfo.executorHost} ${executorAdded.executorInfo.totalCores} cores")

}
```